# Typescript with Angular 1.6 and browserfy

Tags: angularjs, typescript, browserify

I'm trying to figure out how to work with angular types in typescript and also be able to bundle the code with browserfy. I followed the typescript [tutorial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html) related to gulp. I installed the angular types with npm and created this simple ts file

```
import * as angular from "angular"
angular.module("test");
console.log("ok");
```

> Error: Cannot find module 'angular'

I have created a [github](https://github.com/alexmaie/angular-browserfy-typescript) repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular) NPM package:

`npm i --save angular`

When you install typescript types packages, e.g. `@types/angular`, you are only installing the type definitions, for example, what will each of the function return (Promise, string, number), what arguments do they accept, etc.

You still need to install the actual project that contains the implementation.

Comment: Yeah, this makes totally sense. Thanks